# How to configure user authentication with dynamic user attributes?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, authentication

I'm new to CakePHP and i want to migrate from my custom lib to CakePHP.

I have, on my custom lib, for user attributes something like this:

`auth_users` table to know the "user_ids":

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `auth_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

`auth_user_attributes` table to store "user attributes":

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `auth_user_attributes` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attribute` text NOT NULL,
  `value` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

So whenever i want an user by user_id, my custom lib returns `$system->auth->user->get(1)` into:

```
Array(
    'fullname' => 'José Moreira',
    'username' => 'Cuss',
    ...
)
```

If i want to save user i have two methods, save an entire array `$system->auth->user->save(user_id,user_attributes_array)` or by attribute `$system->auth->user->put(user_id, user_attribute, user_attribute_value)`

How can i do something like this on CakePHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to redesign your schema to fit CakePHP conventions. Otherwise you will loose a lot of automagic and I see no sense for you to migrate to Cake if nobody forces you. `User` cannot have more than one `fullname` or `username`. There is no reason to put `fullname` and `username` into another table. Follow [Simple Authentication and Authorization Application turorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) and you will have no pain.

Then you can save user attributes by calling [User->UserAttribute->saveMany()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array).

Comment: Plus the fact that cake expects all tables to have primary key (auto increment or uuid) for saves to properly work. Not sure if the OP skipped them in his example or the tables actually don't have primary keys.