# CakePHP Auth: How to authenticate with email having multiple emails on the same account?

Tags: email, cakephp, authentication

I'm starting with CakePHP. I've build an users table logging with `email` instead of `username`...
Problem is that i wan't to have, not one, but many emails for each user so they can login into the same account using any of their emails, almost like facebook does.

My question, once that CakePHP doesn't allows me to create dynamicly multiple attributes (see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783059/how-to-configure-user-authentication-with-dynamic-user-attributes)), what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to setup two tables in your database:

- USERS
- USER_EMAILS

In your USERS table, you store whatever you want about your users:

- id
- username
- fname
- lname
- telephone
- etc...

Then you setup your USER_EMAILS table to reference the USERS table with a foreign key:

- user_id (foreign key)
- email

Make the "email" a unique index to prevent duplicates.

Now whenever you lookup an email address in the USER_EMAILS table (say at login), you will get a reference to the USER you are supposed to be working with.

Does that make sense?

Comment: in short: "User" hasMany "UserEmail" (1:N). Login via UserEmail model (custom login then)

Answer (score 1):

You probablly need to do what @Petar answered... in order to store multiple emails for each user.

To authenticate the users, you migth need to create a [custom authentication object](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects) where you'll have to create an authenticate() method that makes the query and returns true if the email-password is correct.

Dont forget to set this new authentication object in your AppController. It should be something like:

**AppController.php**

```
// Pass settings in $components array
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'MultipleEmails'
        )
    )
);
```

**Component/Auth/MultipleEmailsAuthenticate.php**

```
class MultipleEmailsAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate {
    public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response) {
        //make your query here and return true or false     
    }
```

If you want some examples on how to write a BaseAuthenticate class, you could read the source files: [BaseAuthenticate](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/base-authenticate) and [FormAuthenticate](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/form-authenticate).

Hope this helps